# HTML5 video tag works in Explorer 11.494 but not in 11.545 (But not really?)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, internet-explorer-11, explorer

There are two machines with Internet Explorer 11.545 except mine, which is 11.494. I've embeded video with the `video` tag.
It works on my machine (seemingly with HTML5), but not on the other two machines, which run the slightly newer version.

I've tried polyfilling (Video for Everybody), and it still doesn't work.

Other than that it works for both Chrome, Edge and Firefox on all machines.

EDIT: I've now tried with another machine with 11.494, and it doesn't work? I am now utterly confused

```
<video width="300" height="169" controls preload="metadata">
    <source src="./videos/2016-Vidéo corporative GESTESS.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="./videos/2016-Vidéo corporative GESTESS.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="300" height="169">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':[{'url':'.%2Fvideos%2F2016-Vid%C3%A9o+corporative+GESTESS.mp4','autoPlay':false}]}" />
    </object>
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Errors in the console? How about a filename more standard than 2016-`Vidéo corporative GESTESS.mp4`? In other words, no spaces or accented characters.

Comment: I agree with @j08691 try changing the file name, get rid of the spaces and `-`

Comment: Did that and still doesn't work. (no worries, I changed the names in the code too)